# How can I yield return an interated object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator

I'm trying to create an iterator to loop over an array using a for..of loop and then yield return each object.  I'm not getting output however, as I'm unsure how to utilize the yield keyword succesfully.

```
let items = ["one", "two", "three"];

function myIterator() {

    for (let i of items) {       
        yield i;
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only use the `yield` keyword in a generator function, i.e. `function* myIterator`. You should be getting a `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. Also please show us how you are calling the function.

Comment: What do you mean by "*yield return each object*"?

Comment: If you are unsure how to use a language feature, StackOverflow is NOT the place to ask a question.  I suggest you go research it using the innumerable resources you can find by simply Googling, for instance https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield  Would you expect this to be a place to ask question about how to write loops?

Answer (score 0):

`yield` is only valid inside a generator function, which you declare with `*`. You also need to call the function and use the generator it returns:

```js
let items = ["one", "two", "three"];

function* myIterator() {
// −−−−−^

    for (let i of items) {       
        yield i;
        // console.log(i);
    }
}

for (const value of myIterator()) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

(Although in this specific case you could use `yield *` to link the generator to the iterator from `items`. The body of `myIterator` would literally be just `yield *items;`. But I'm assuming `myIterator` will have more logic added to it...)

Comment: …though of course for this usage, `const myIterator = () => items.values()` would be much simpler and more efficient.

Comment: @Bergi - Yes, or `yield* items`. But I assume `myIterator` will get more logic.